# Text processing in bash - extracting information between multiple HTML tags and outputting it into CSV format

Tags: bash, export-to-csv, text-processing

I have multiple .xml files. I need the information between tags, which I can easily get with grep, but I can't seem to be able to do anything with it after.

```
grep -oP '<topic>(.*)</teema>|<number>(.*)</number>|<participants>(.*)</participants>' *.xml --colour
```

The output looks likes this:

```
<topic>Negotiations</topic>
<number>1</number>
<participants><name>J. Roland</name><name>M. King</name></participants>
```

I want the information between the tags extracted and printed in a CSV format like this:

```
1; Negotiations; J. Roland, M. King
```

**grep** doesn't seem all that useful here, I tried grouping with sed, but what I used doesn't return anything:

```
sed -n 's:.*<topic>\(.*\)</topic>.*<number>\(.*\)</number>.*<participants>\(.*\)participants>:\1\2\3:p' *.xml
```

I'm open to suggestions, tho I only recently started with text processing, so there is a lot I'm not familiar with yet.

Edit: I checked out the mentioned topic in the comments, it talks about making new lines with the sed command. I imagine I might need to do the opposite here instead and remove new lines to be able to capture all the information I need, but I'd really like to know how to solve the example given here first.

Comment: Choose the right tool first. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet or something comparable).

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak thanks, I checked out the other topic, it seems to be dealing with a different matter and hasn't helped with my problem

Comment: @Cyrus thanks as well, I'll keep the suggestions in mind, but I would really like to figure out a solution in bash as well.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858

Comment: In addition to `xmlstarlet` have a look at the `html2text` package. It will remove the tags leaving only the text (look at the `-utf8` option depending on your charset)